# Saltos de línea en Mail creado en Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando en un proyecto bajo Laravel 8 que tiene que enviar mails desde una de sus pantallas y estoy teniendo el siguiente inconveniente: todo lo referente al despacho del mail en sí, ya está resuelto y funcionando, pero lo que no, y de ahí mi solicitud de vuestra ayuda, es que uso un textarea para que el usuario puedo escribir el cuerpo del mail, pero al pasar dicho textarea al mailable creado a tal efecto, en el mail despachado, no se respetan los saltos de línea que fueran dados en la redacción del cuerpo del mail en mi textarea.

Les muestro un par de imágenes para ver si sirven de orientación en pos de resolver este tema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación, les muestro brevemente el código que estoy utilizando en el botón ENVIAR

```
    public function EnviarMail(){

    $correo = new FacturaspendientesMailable($this->mailAsunto, $this->mailCuerpo);

    $saldoActual=0;
    $var_saldoctacte=0;
    if ($this->codClienteSeleccionado!=""){
        $facpend = Facturaspendientes::where('cod_client', $this->codClienteSeleccionado)->orderBy('fecha_vto', 'ASC')->get();
        $saldoActual = Facturaspendientes::where('cod_client', $this->codClienteSeleccionado)->sum('importe');
        $dtosCliente = Cliente::with('relacCtaCte')->where('cod_cliente', $this->codClienteSeleccionado)->get();
        $var_saldoctacte = number_format($dtosCliente[0]->relacCtaCte->saldo_cc,2);
    }

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('Clientes.listfacpenPDF',
        [
            'codCliente'=>$this->codClienteSeleccionado,
            'facturasPendi'=>$facpend,
            'saldoActual'=>$saldoActual,
            'var_saldoctacte'=>$var_saldoctacte,
            'dtosCliente'=>$dtosCliente,
        ])->save(public_path('historialarchiv/') . 'archivo.pdf');

    $correo->attach(public_path('historialarchiv/') . 'archivo.pdf', ['as'=>'archivo.pdf', 'mime'=>'application/pdf',]);

    Mail::to($this->destPrincipal)->send($correo);

    $this->VerFormMail=false;
    $this->emit('EmailEnviado');

}
```

Previamente a enviar el mail, se genera un archivo pdf con un listado y luego es anexado al mail, de ahí las demás líneas que no hacen al envío puntual del mail.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class FacturaspendientesMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject;
    public $cuerpo;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($mailAsunto, $mailCuerpo)
    {
        $this->subject = $mailAsunto;
        $this->cuerpo = $mailCuerpo;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.facturaspendientes', ['body'=>$this->cuerpo]);
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase que dispara el mail y por último, les muestro el html del mail

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{$body}}
</body>
</html>
```

Bueno, espero me hayan podido interpretar y quedo a la espera de cualquier comentario que me  pueda ayudar.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Proba sin escapar los datos https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Hice la prueba con la siguiente sintaxis  {!! $body !!}, pero sigue igual